# Properties of Hardy operator $T(u)(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x u(t)dt$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $u$ be a measurable function in $[0,1]$ and define $T:L^p(0,1)\to L^p(0,1)$ by 
$Tu(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x u(t)dt\quad\forall x \in [0,1]$. Let $1<p<\infty$. Prove that $T$ is bounded, non-compact. Determine the spectral radius of $T$ and prove that in the case $p=2$ the operator $TT^*-T^*T$ has range $1$. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: miserable function???

Comment: Poor little function... :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the proof that $T$ is bounded:

[Hardy's Inequality for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83946/hardys-inequality-for-integrals/95399#95399)

Here is the exact calculation of its norm:

[Computing the best constant in classical Hardy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126889/computing-the-best-constant-in-classical-hardys-inequality/126973)

To find its spectral radius, use the formula $\text{radius}(T) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|^{1/n}$

To compute $T^n$ and $T^*$, look at [http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/hardy.html](http://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Estephen/preprints/hardy.html)

Here is compactness https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262221/is-hf-1-over-x-int-0x-ftdt-compact?rq=1

Probably this will get marked as a duplicate, but I don't see anywhere spectral radius was asked before.

Another way to find a lower bound for the spectral radius is to consider $u(t) = t^{-1/r}$ for $r>p$.  This will give eigenfunctions.

Comment: You beat me to this! Ok, i'll just add that $$T^*(u)(x)=\int_x^1 t^{-1}u(t)dt$$$$(TT^*-T^*T)(u)=\left(\int_0^1 u(t)dt\right) \chi_{(0,1)}$$

Comment: I had the advantage that I had it all written up beforehand!

Comment: So what is the final formula for $T^n$ ? I can't understand from that paper.

Comment: It's on page 5.  In this special case $$ T^{n+1} f(x) =\frac1x \int_0^x \frac{(\log(x/t))^n}{n!} u(t) \, dt $$

Comment: And to find a lower bound on $\|T^{n+1}\|$, assume $u(t)$ is decreasing (because you only need to consider specific functions to find the lower bounds).  Then $$T^{n+1}f(x) \ge \frac1x \int_0^{ax} \frac{(\log(x/t)^n}{n!} u(t) dt \ge \frac1a \frac{|\log(a)|^n}{n!} u(ax) $$ for $0<a<1$.  Then use $\|u(a\cdot)\|_p = a^{-1/p} \|u\|_p$.  Choose $a$ and $n$ suitably to show the spectral radius of $T$ is bounded below by $\|T\|$.

Comment: Maybe there is an easier way, though.

Comment: I think I found the easier way and I added it to the end of the solution.

Comment: is there a problem writing $\int^{x}_{1} \frac {g (t)}{t} $ ? thats what I get as adjont

Comment: @User2313 That is exactly the negative of what I obtained.  Maybe you made a sign error somewhere, because I am rather certain I am correct.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Im sure you are I just cant get where I go wrong, flipping $\int^{x}_{0} f = - \int^{x}_{1} f$ right?

Comment: @User2313 No, $\int_1^x = - \int_x^1$.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith I cant see how this appear..we are integrating g(t)/t  from zero to x in the partial integration how do we get to start from 1?

Comment: @User2313 $\langle g,Tf\rangle = \int_{y=0}^1 g(y) \frac1y \int_{x=0}^y f(x) \, dx \, dy = \int_{x=0}^1 f(x) \int_{y=x}^1 \frac{g(y)} y \, dy \, dx = \langle T^* g,f \rangle$.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith donst that suggest we define a primitve for g(t)/t beyond 1?

Comment: @User2313 How can $g(t)/t$ have a primitive when $t>1$?  We don't even have that $g(t)$ is defined there, since $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I was doing integration by parts, considering   $\int_{0}^{y} f(y) dy$ as one function and $g(t)/t$ as the other, integrating the latter but from $0$ to $x$, but this donst add up to what you have here. It looks like you have been integrating $g(t)/t$ from $x$ to $1$, then made the flipp suggested a few comments up.

Comment: Correction it look like you been integrating $g(t)/t$ from $1$ to $x$

Comment: @User2313 But I meant for $0 \le x \le 1$, and I used $\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith are we defining a primitve from $1$ to $x$ for $x \le 1$ , is that possible?

Comment: @User2313 Yes.  It's just a matter of notation.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith right, this is kinda of topic but could one define a primivite for $f$ being any continous function from an arbitrary point $a$ as $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y) dy$ ? ofc this would only be the primitve for $f$ on this partricular intevall. It seems reasonable..but still kind of wierd.

Comment: A primitive for $f$ would be any function of the form you gave plus a constant.  Making $a$ arbitrary isn't quite enough, e.g. consider the case $f = 0$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith how can one just choose this primitive to be $0$ at $1$ ? $g$ is predetermined right? We need $g(1)=0$ I think, otherwise we get boundary terms. And since g is predet. we cant just choose

Comment: @User1 You can choose any primitive you like, as long as you are consistent (use the same one throughout).

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith let $g$ be cts(given that we later want to extend the adjont to $L^{p}$ later) and let $G(x)= g(1)+ \int_{1}^{x} g(t) $. Im sorry for being persistant but at what point do we have the freedom to choose here? Are you suggesting we take the constant $C=-g(1)$? I thought the "constant of integraton" was the number $g(1)$

Comment: I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156376/definite-integral-and-constant-of-integration  ,  there it was :)

Comment: I'm afraid that the compactness link is broken?

Comment: @TrostAft I fixed the $T^n$ and $T^*$ link.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith It's good that that one got fixed too, but I'm referring to the link after "Here is compactness [...]". I get redirected to a Page not Found screen, on which it states that the question had been removed for reasons of moderation. Perhaps it was removed as a duplicate?

Comment: @TrostAft Yes, I don't have any control over that.  If you can find a better reference, please let me know.